# how to code int text at the bottom of rightside in checkboxlisttile with gridview

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, checkboxlist

[image]

I have a question about alignment of checkboxListTile with gridview.

How can I code int text at the bottom of leftside in checkboxListTile with gridview.

Maybe I think that "secondary" but I am not sure..

This is my code

```
return GridView.count(
                primary: false,
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                children: workoutList
                                .map(
                            (workout) => Material(
                              color: Colors.teal[400],
                              child: CheckboxListTile(
                                  title:
                                  Text(
                                    workout.title,
                                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                                  ),
                                  value: workout.isDone,
                                  onChanged: (bool value) {
                                  workout.isDone = !workout.isDone;
                                  model.reload();
                                  },
                              ),
                            ),

                            )
                                .toList(),
                );
```

Answer (score 0):

I edited your code to look like this:

```
return GridView.count(
                primary: false,
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                children: workoutList
                                .map(
                            (workout) => Material(
                              color: Colors.teal[400],
                              child: Column(
                                 children: <Widget>[
                                     CheckboxListTile(
                                  title:
                                  Text(
                                    workout.title,
                                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                                  ),
                                  value: workout.isDone,
                                  onChanged: (bool value) {
                                  workout.isDone = !workout.isDone;
                                  model.reload();
                                  },
                              ),
                                    Align(
                                    alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                                     child: Text("count"),
                                       ),
                                  ],
                              ),
                            ),

                            )
                                .toList(),
                );
```

By using the Align widget, we are able to align the Text widget to the bottomRight hand corner

Comment: I coded like your proposal but align is not bottom of right...

Comment: Sorry about the right side instead of left side, after you changed it did it give you what you needed?